# system runtime error from ArcHydro

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, windows-7, arc-hydro, research

I am getting the below error during execution of archydro.
"system runtime interoperservices com exception (0x80004005): error HRESULT E_FAIL"

I tried all options available on internet to solve this but no luck.

What is the cause of these type of issues? Is this related to application or os ?
What is the perfect fix if it is caused by arcgis/hydro or os ?

I am using windows7, 64-bit, Arcgis10.

Comment: What steps could someone follow to reproduce what you are seeing?

Comment: I tried to execute Longest Flow Path for Catchment.I am not sure if you will get the same error.Pls let me know, if you test it and you are getting the same error or not.

Comment: Does it fail on all catchments, or just for a particular one?

Comment: In attribute table, few ID's are generated but most having "null".

Comment: If this question is still in need of an Answer would you be able to refresh it with your latest understanding of the problem and versions you are now seeing it in, please?