# Fill sinks error in arcHydro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, arc-hydro, error-010067

I am working on a project that is modeling runoff at a county level. The DEM used is lidar derived and has a 5 ft resolution. The general workflow I am flowing is

1. Sink evaluation
2. Sink Selection (to give a minimum drainage area)
3. Fill sinks (using the deranged polygon from the sink evaluation and the 'Use IsSink field' option).

When I run the fill sinks tool I receive the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80041098): ERROR 010429: Error in GRID IO: MtVatBldNew: Value range for c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\arcc79c\ah2014~4\tmp2675 exceeds 100000 .
>   ERROR 010429: Error in GRID IO: and number of unique values exceeds 500 ..
>   ERROR 010236: Error in building VAT.
>   ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
>   at ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoAnalyst.RasterConversionOpClass.ToRasterDataset(IGeoDataset dataset, String rasterFormat, IWorkspace pWorkspace, String name)
>   at ESRI.APWR.ApHydro.ArcHydroOp.FillSinks(ApLayers& aplayers, Boolean useIsSink, Boolean fillAll, Double fillLimit, ITrackCancel trackCancel, IGPMessage messages, String& exMessage) in C:\Builds\HydroSolutions\10.1_ArcHydro\Sources\ArcHydroTools\src\ApHydro\ArcHydroOp.vb:line 57592
>   Failed to execute (FillSinks).

I thought this was telling me that the DEM was too large in size, so I tried running the tool again with several subsets by using a polygon to determine the processing extent. This results in the same error and I am not sure why. I have tried the usual fixes (deleting temp files, checking output locations, using the toolbox vs. the toolbar) and the error still occurs.

In order to get the DEM to a smaller size, it was converted from float to integer so I thought the VAT error pertained to that. I reran the tools using the float based DEM and received the same error.

I have also tried using small subsets of the raster to see if that is the problem, and I have the same error.

Can anyone offer insight on this or help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem, I suspect the floating spatial analyst license, because it generates interuptions of geoprocessing !!

Comment: Is the original file in TIF format? I'm a beginning or intermediate user, but a lot of issues trace back to not-in-TIF. I was trying to use the fill tool on a non TIF raster and receiving error messages. I finally converted it to TIF and it worked just fine afterwards. Hopefully this works.

Comment: What were the precise steps (all tools and parameter values) that you performed to see this error?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common error when using ArcHydro, although the exact text and in which function it appears might differ slightly.

You should check out the answer and comments in [Error running Arc Hydro tools function in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57163/error-running-archydro-tools-function-in-arcmap).

But in short, what is most likely to solve your problem is to store all data and your project on `C:/` instead of a network drive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Before I started I made sure all inputs, outputs and workspaces were on the C:/ drive and the error continues. I can get past the sink evaluation tool, it is the fill sinks where I get the VAT error. I believe I have tried all the typical error fixes, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: [This](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/48100-ArcHydro-Problem-Solvers) is the "official error thread" on the archydro forum. Check it out and see if you can catch something new! Keeping short names and paths is also a good thing.

Comment: Also, from the answer in the linked question: *3. Increase the max number of unique values to render*.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I am having trouble finding things I have not tried. I am not sure what else I can try besides using a different pc.