# "ERROR 010214: Unable to read STA of..." while running Arc Hydro Geoprocessing Tools

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.3, arc-hydro

Today I tried running the `Combined Terrain with Unknown Sink and Stream Locations` Tool from the Arc Hydro Toolset (**version 10.3.0.58, ArcMap 10.3**). As input I used a DTM with values between -10 and 19 meters. After 20 min (the DTM is rather big: 4,12 GB) the process fails with several error messages, the one mentioned in the title is the first.

What is meant by "**unable to read STA**"?

```
Executing: CombinedTerrainwithUnknownSinkandStreamLocations dtm_2013 c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoly c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkDA c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPolygon c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoint c:\archydro\Layers\SinkPolyGrid c:\archydro\Layers\SinkPntGrid c:\archydro\Layers\Fil c:\archydro\Layers\Fdr c:\archydro\Layers\FdrSinkAdj c:\archydro\Layers\Fac c:\archydro\Layers\SinkWshGrid c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkWatershed c:\archydro\Layers\Str c:\archydro\Layers\StrLnk c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\DrainageLine c:\archydro\Layers\Link c:\archydro\Layers\Cat c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\Catchment c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\AdjointCatchment c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Catchment_FS c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\DrainageLine_FS
Start Time: Mon Dec 07 10:23:41 2015
Executing (Sink Evaluation): SinkEvaluation dtm_2013 c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoly c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkDA 1
Start Time: Mon Dec 07 10:23:42 2015
Running script SinkEvaluation...
c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers does not exist.
Feature Dataset c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers does not exist in database c:\archydro\archydro.gdb.
Creating feature dataset Layers
--Computing flow direction from DEM...
--Computing sinks...
--Computing drainage area for sinks...
Performing zonal fill...
ERROR 010214: Unable to read STA of c:\archydro\dtm_2013.
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
Failed to execute (ZonalFill).

Completed script SinkEvaluation...
Succeeded at Mon Dec 07 10:45:10 2015 (Elapsed Time: 21 minutes 28 seconds)
Executing (Create Sink Structures): CreateSinkStructures dtm_2013 c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoly c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPolygon c:\archydro\Layers\SinkPolyGrid c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoint c:\archydro\Layers\SinkPntGrid # #
Start Time: Mon Dec 07 10:45:11 2015
Running script CreateSinkStructures...
ERROR 000732: Input Deranged Polygon Feature Class: Dataset c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoly does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Create Sink Structures).
Failed at Mon Dec 07 10:45:11 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,10 seconds)
Failed to execute (CombinedTerrainwithUnknownSinkandStreamLocations).
Failed at Mon Dec 07 10:45:11 2015 (Elapsed Time: 21 minutes 29 seconds)
```

I tried calculating statistics which wasn't working (I got no error message but after the process there were no statistics) so I converted the GRID Raster to TIF. After this the "Combined Terrain with Unknown Sink and Stream Locations" Tool run for over one hour but again finished with an error.

```
Executing: CombinedTerrainwithUnknownSinkandStreamLocations dtm_2013_CopyRaster.tif c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoly c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkDA c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPolygon c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoint c:\archydro\Layers\SinkPolyGrid c:\archydro\Layers\SinkPntGrid c:\archydro\Layers\Fil c:\archydro\Layers\Fdr c:\archydro\Layers\FdrSinkAdj c:\archydro\Layers\Fac c:\archydro\Layers\SinkWshGrid c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkWatershed c:\archydro\Layers\Str c:\archydro\Layers\StrLnk c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\DrainageLine c:\archydro\Layers\Link c:\archydro\Layers\Cat c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\Catchment c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\AdjointCatchment c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Catchment_FS c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\DrainageLine_FS
Start Time: Mon Dec 07 17:09:29 2015
Executing (Sink Evaluation): SinkEvaluation dtm_2013_CopyRaster.tif c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoly c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkDA 1
Start Time: Mon Dec 07 17:09:31 2015
Running script SinkEvaluation...
c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers does not exist.
Feature Dataset c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers does not exist in database c:\archydro\archydro.gdb.
Creating feature dataset Layers
--Computing flow direction from DEM...
--Computing sinks...
--Computing drainage area for sinks...
Performing zonal fill...
--Calculating zonal statistics on sink watersheds: sinkdepth...
ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error.
Failed to execute (ZonalStatisticsAsTable).

Completed script SinkEvaluation...
Succeeded at Mon Dec 07 18:19:11 2015 (Elapsed Time: 1 hours 9 minutes 39 seconds)
Executing (Create Sink Structures): CreateSinkStructures dtm_2013_CopyRaster.tif c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoly c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPolygon c:\archydro\Layers\SinkPolyGrid c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoint c:\archydro\Layers\SinkPntGrid # #
Start Time: Mon Dec 07 18:19:11 2015
Running script CreateSinkStructures...
ERROR 000732: Input Deranged Polygon Feature Class: Dataset c:\archydro\archydro.gdb\Layers\SinkPoly does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Create Sink Structures).
Failed at Mon Dec 07 18:19:12 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,10 seconds)
Failed to execute (CombinedTerrainwithUnknownSinkandStreamLocations).
Failed at Mon Dec 07 18:19:12 2015 (Elapsed Time: 1 hours 9 minutes 42 seconds)
```

Comment: I assume you have used the Modelbuilder-model. It would seem it gets stuck on Sink evaluation (even on Zonal statistics as table), which, since the upgrade to 10.2, has been nothing but trouble to run. I'm really sorry to hear that the problems persist in 10.3. There is now a pretty extensive list of things you can do to get past it, but none is certain to fix everything. See [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57163/error-running-archydro-tools-function-in-arcmap) for hints, also note the link to Esri Forum in a comment.

Comment: You should also try to run the functions in order, manually. Then you have a bit more control, which is needed in a case like this.

Comment: I followed all the recommendations in the above mentioned links but still get the ERROR 999998

Comment: I wish I had a solution. Try emailing ESRI/Arc hydro team with sample data and see if they can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error 010214 could be fixed by calculating the statistics as proposed by Farid Cher.
The only solution I found to avoid the Error 999998 was to clip my raster dataset to a much smaller area. Now the "Combined Terrain with Unknown Sink and Stream Locations" tool works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click the Esri Grid (DEM) data in ArcCatalog-->Calculate Statistics

If it doesn't solve, then export your DEM to another raster format (e.g. Tif) and recalculate the statistics and use ArcHydro.

See ESRI help page for this error, [010214 : Unable to read value of value.](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/ArcGISDesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00vq0000000p010214)

Comment: This fixed a part of the problem, I updated my question

Comment: The zone raster dataset might not have an attribute table. Zonal Statistics requires the zone dataset contain an attribute table. see [here](http://support.esri.com/ja/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/18414)

Comment: Which raster dataset do you mean? The input DEM? This indeed has no attribute table. If you are talking about the "zonalfi_wate1" which is generated during the process: I can't add it to the TOC because ArcMap states "Invalid raster dataset. Failed to create raster layer". It is also impossible to view its properties in catalog.